# facebook Sdk 3.1.1 Access_token Issue

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

i am using the following code to get the access_token

```
    <?php
//include the Facebook PHP SDK
include_once 'facebook.php';

//instantiate the Facebook library with the APP ID and APP SECRET
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'REPLACE WITH APP ID',
    'secret' => 'REPLACE WITH APP SECRET',
    'cookie' => true
));

//Get the FB UID of the currently logged in user
$user = $facebook->getUser();

//if the user has already allowed the application, you'll be able to get his/her FB UID
if($user) {
    //start the session if needed
    if( session_id() ) {

    } else {
        session_start();
    }

    //do stuff when already logged in

    //get the user's access token
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    //check permissions list
    $permissions_list = $facebook->api(
        '/me/permissions',
        'GET',
        array(
            'access_token' => $access_token
        )
    );

    //check if the permissions we need have been allowed by the user
    //if not then redirect them again to facebook's permissions page
    $permissions_needed = array('publish_stream', 'read_stream', 'offline_access', 'manage_pages');
    foreach($permissions_needed as $perm) {
        if( !isset($permissions_list['data'][0][$perm]) || $permissions_list['data'][0][$perm] != 1 ) {
            $login_url_params = array(
                'scope' => 'publish_stream,read_stream,offline_access,manage_pages',
                'fbconnect' =>  1,
                'display'   =>  "page",
                'next' => 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
            );
            $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($login_url_params);
            header("Location: {$login_url}");
            exit();
        }
    }

    //if the user has allowed all the permissions we need,
    //get the information about the pages that he or she managers
    $accounts = $facebook->api(
        '/me/accounts',
        'GET',
        array(
            'access_token' => $access_token
        )
    );

    //save the information inside the session
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;
    $_SESSION['accounts'] = $accounts['data'];
    //save the first page as the default active page
    $_SESSION['active'] = $accounts['data'][0];

    //redirect to manage.php
    header('Location: manage.php');
} else {
    //if not, let's redirect to the ALLOW page so we can get access
    //Create a login URL using the Facebook library's getLoginUrl() method
    $login_url_params = array(
        'scope' => 'publish_stream,read_stream,offline_access,manage_pages',
        'fbconnect' =>  1,
        'display'   =>  "page",
        'next' => 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
    );
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($login_url_params);

    //redirect to the login URL on facebook
    header("Location: {$login_url}");
    exit();
}

?>
```

But it is not getting back to my redirect URL,  Firefox shows the following error

```
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.


    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
    cookies.
```

Comment: Don't forget that the `offline_access` permission is now deprecated, see: http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put login and auth process in another file like **login.php**
And then when you need to authenticate, then use `include_once "login.php";` from your app.
**Replace your-app-namespace.**

```
 <?php
//login.php
require 'lib/facebook.php';
require 'lib/fbconfig.php';





if (isset($_GET['code'])){
        header("Location:http://apps.facebook.com/your-app-namespace");
        exit;
    }
$user=null;




//Facebook Authentication part
    $user       = $facebook->getUser();
    // We may or may not have this data based 
    // on whether the user is logged in.
    // If we have a $user id here, it means we know 
    // the user is logged into
    // Facebook, but we don’t know if the access token is valid. An access
    // token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

    $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
                'scope'         => 'email,read_mailbox,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location,read_stream,user_work_history,user_about_me,user_hometown'
            )
    );

    if ($user) {
      try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        //you should use error_log($e); instead of printing the info on browser
        d($e);  // d is a debug function defined at the end of this file
        $user = null;
      }
    }

    if (!$user) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
        exit;
    }

    //get user basic description
    $userInfo           = $facebook->api("/$user");

    function d($d){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($d);
        echo '</pre>';
    }




?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
 //redirect to the login URL on facebook
header("Location: {$login_url}");
```

Try using :

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
```

Comment: it just starts refreshing page continously